# Python BeautifulSoup Error BsObj

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just bought a book to show me how to scrape websites but the first example right off the bat is not working for me - so now I am a little upset that I bought the book in the first place but I would like to try and get it going.

In Python 3.5 my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
BsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print(bsObj.h1)*
```

Here is the error I am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Lib/site-packages/bs4/test.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       BsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
>
> File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py",
>   line 153, in **init**
>       builder = builder_class()
>
> File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder_htmlparser.py",
>   line 39, in **init**
>       return super(HTMLParserTreeBuilder, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Any ideas would be super helpful?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you transcribed the code from the book. `bsObj` is not named consistently and there is an unnecessary `*` after `print()`. It will work after you change those two things.

Also note that `read()` is not needed and that it's better to define the parser, otherwise you will get a warning.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(bsObj.h1)
```

Comment: Thank you - on the typo I copied my latest file which I had changed the spelling around - I did both suggestions and am still getting the error.

Comment: Yes the same error I originally posted.  I had to download Python 35 for this book and was using 27 previously - this caused issues I could not fix or find a fix so I uninstalled both and reload 35 - my gut is telling me I did something wrong when installing either 35 or BS.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Run `python -V` to check which version is in use.

Comment: getting this message when I type that in IDLE Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    python -V
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Comment: Here you go - my bad  - 3.5.1

Comment: Try updating Beautiful Soup with `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it works for you now. If my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check mark.

Comment: You bet - I am just going to hit the grey check next to your first comment back to me?  I don't want to do this wrong

Comment: No, there should be a check mark symbol on the left side of my answer. It's below the downvote arrow. You can also upvote my answer if you want.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't upvote anything. Hitting it twice reverts it, so you should really only do it once.

Comment: Every time I hit the upvote it changes the 0 to 1 and then right back to 0

Comment: One click should change it to 1. Another click would undo it.

Comment: Okay because I am so new to SO my upvote will not be public.  One I get to a higher level I promise you I will come back and upvote you.  Thanks again

Comment: That's correct, you need at least 15 reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just had some typos BsObj not bsObj in print line.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
BsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print(BsObj.h1)
```

Comment: bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(bsObj.h1)

Comment: This is what I changed:

Comment: glad to have helped ;)

Comment: I am still getting the same error I originally got:  I apologize

Comment: hmm... I ran the above code I posted and it worked just fine. Could you try opening up python shell and typing from bs4 import BeautifulSoup to check that that works?

Comment: I typed it in and nothing happened - no error messages